# C#: Access modifier make method invoke differently

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

First of all, here is the code and the result is what  expect:

code 1:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class DerivedClass : Base
    {
        public new void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived class");
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base class");
        }
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            Base bc = new Base();

            dc.Run();
            bc.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

result 1:

> Derived class
>
> Base class

---

However, if I change both of two classes' `Run()` access modifiers from`public` to `protected`, thing became out of expect:

code 2:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class DerivedClass : Base
    {
        protected new void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived class");
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        protected void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base class");
        }
       
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
            Base bc = new Base();

            dc.Run();
            bc.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

result 2:

> Base class
>
> Base class

My question is, under the circumstances that `protected` also allow the derived class to access the base class as `public`, Why does the result become different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DerivedClass.Run` is protected, so `Base` doesn't even see it. It invokes the `Run` method inherited from `Base`.

Comment: Just to clarify, changing `Base.Run` to `protected` does not change a thing in this case - it is still visible to all `Base` members.

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` function is in `Base`, and has access to the public/private/protected members on instances of `Base` and access to the public members on instances of `DerivedClass`.